# event listener on div reach top Angular

Tags: angular

Is this any way to trigger event when div reach top of the window in Angular? I need to fire animation when client scroll to specific place with id but can't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Comment: @KrzysztofLa unfortunately, no

Comment: @krzysztofla with code refactoring your answer is working, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  this.scroll = event.srcElement.scrollTop
  ...
}
```

and your specific div

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

getting the actual scroll position

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Documentation:

- [HostListener & HostBinding](https://ng2.codecraft.tv/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/)